# How to update multiple Columns in T-SQL from Multikey tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I'm facing a problem updating a Table from another table values.

Suppose I have:

TableA (keyA, keyB, fieldA, fieldB)

TableB (keyA, keyB, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC)

And I want to update the rows in the TableA that compares in the Table B with the TableB values.

I tried this way:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET FieldA = 
(
SELECT FieldA
FROM TableA W INNER JOIN TableB as V
    ON  W.keyA = V.keyA AND
        W.keyB = V.keyB
WHERE W.KeyA = V.KeyA AND
        W.keyB = V.KeyB AND 
) 
FROM TableA PK INNER JOIN TableB  AS I ON
TableA.keyA = TableB.keyA AND TableA.keyB = TableB.keyB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is very complicated. You can further simply into this,

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.fieldA = b.fieldA,
        a.fieldB = b.fieldB
FROM    TableA a
        INNER JOIN TableB b
            ON  a.keyA = b.keyA AND
                a.keyB = b.keyB
```